# SQL not Equal to & Equal to Operator Use

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select those macs which are in state 5 and not in state 4 from below table.
[image]

I used this query,

```
select mac from tableabc where state=5 and state !=4;
```

but its same result as

[image]

```
where state=5
```

Comment: state is a number or a varchar?

Comment: The where clause contains predicates which must be true for *each row* that will be returned in the result set. You cannot make *multirow* assertions there as plain predicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use not in

```
select mac from tableabc
where state=5
and mac not in ( select mac from tableabc where state=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses conditional aggregation:

```
select mac
from tableabc
where state in (4, 5)
having min(state) = 5;
```

If the values of `state` are not "ordered", then you can add `and min(state) = max(state)`.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way is to use not exists here:

```
SELECT Mac 
FROM TableABC AS T
WHERE State = 5
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM TableABC T2
                   WHERE T2.Mac = T.Mac
                     AND T2.State = 4 )
```

Answer (score -1):

Please Try this.

select mac from tableabc where state in(5)

Answer (score -1):

You can use below queries

Query 1(Since you have only one value in the state field , no need of checking about 4 just only check 5):

select mac from tableabc where state=5

Query 2:

SELECT Mac FROM TableABC T1 WHERE T1.State = 5
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM TableABC WHERE T2.Mac = T1.Mac AND T2.State = 4 )

Query 3:

select mac from tableabc where state=5
and 
mac not in ( select mac from tableabc where state=4)